# Do Henselian extensions have left lifting property with respect to smooth morphisms?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider the following commutative diagram of schemes: 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
T @>{}>> X\\
@VVV @VVV\\
T' @>{}>> Y
\end{CD}

where  $T\hookrightarrow T'$ is a Henselian extension and $X\to Y$ is a smooth morphism. Can one always find a morphism $T'\to X$ such that the following diagram is commutative:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
 T & \rightarrow & X 
\\
\downarrow & \nearrow & \downarrow 
\\
T' & \rightarrow & Y 
\end{array}
$$

If $T\hookrightarrow T'$ is a first order thickening , this is just the claim that smooth implies formally smooth. It follows that the claim is true if we replace $T'$ by its completion along T. 
What about the general case?

We are mainly interested in the case when $T$ is a spectrum of a field $F$. In this case, $T'$ is a spectrum of Henselian ring with residue field $F$.

In fact, we did not find the notion of Henselian extensions in the literature (though it looks rather natural to have). we will be grateful for a reference for this notion too.

Answer (score 5):

In the local case this is a well known property of henselian rings. It is standard when $X \to Y$ is étale; in the general case it follows from the fact that any smooth maps is Zariski-locally a composite $X \to \mathbb{A}^n_Y \to Y$, where $X \to \mathbb{A}^n_Y$ is étale.

About the general case, for the lifting property to hold you need $T$ to be affine. I don't know what a "henselian extension" is; if it is of the type $\operatorname{Spec}(A/I) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec}A$, where $(A,I)$ is a henselian pair, I would suspect that the answer is still positive, but I don't know a reference.

Comment: Is it still true (in the affine case) if we replace smooth by formally smooth?